# How to retrieve last 24-hours data from Spark DataFrame (Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to retrieve the last 24-hours data from my DataFrame.

```
val data = spark.read.parquet(path_to_parquet_file)
data.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

var df = spark.sql("SELECT datetime, product_PK FROM table WHERE datetime BETWEEN (datetime - 24*3600000) AND datetime")
```

However, I do not know how to convert `datetime` to milliseconds using Spark SQL (Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11).

I can do it using DataFrame, but don't know how to merge everything together:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp

df = df.withColumn("unix_timestamp",unix_timestamp(col("datetime"))).drop("datetime")
```

Comment: def
unix_timestamp(s: Column): Column
  can help you. Just give a try.

Comment: @IshanKumar: Do you mean this?: `spark.sql("SELECT datetime, product_PK FROM table WHERE unix_timestamp(datetime) BETWEEN (unix_timestamp(datetime) - 86400) AND unix_timestamp(datetime)")` Since unix_timestamp gives time in seconds, I should probably use 86400 in order to get 24 hours. Right?